# Identify this alien invasion movie with invisible aliens

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, action

There was a movie that came out about 1-3 years ago at most that was about an alien race that invaded Earth and they hid in plain sight, and would literally snuff people right out of thin air. I think something happened in the atmosphere that let people know that they were in the area.

I also remember from the trailer, 2-3 white people were walking in the middle of the street talking and gasping, and something happened in the atmosphere and they knew the aliens were there. I think they had flashlights or something.

Any ideas what this movie is?

Comment: Any idea of any of the actors in this movie were? A description of one of the actors could help. -Gary R Feroz

Comment: Part of that reminds me of The Happening trailers (did not see the movie), and also Spielberg's War of The Worlds.

Comment: The movie was "Our Darkest Hour". It stunk, but had decent special effects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not conclusive, but you might be referring to [The Darkest Hour](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1093357/)

It's a 2011 sci-fi movie about a an invasion of invisible aliens set in Moscow with some American teenagers as the main protagonists.

Comment: watched that movie and can understand why someone would forget what movie it was. ;)